# Defining a struct with member structs

Tags: c, components, struct

I am trying to define a Sprite structure that contains three member structures (defined in other headers).  For some reason, the compiler gives errors for the outside structs:

C2061 error: identifier 'GraphicsComponent'

C2061 error: identifier 'PhysicsComponent'

AFObjectFactory.h
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ps9DvgQG

AFObjectFactory.c
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HTEmSkdu

AFGraphics.h 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GpsXfy1n

AFGraphics.c
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cm3s6Nqg

AFPhysics.h
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DmQKBxpW

AFPhysics.c
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tsVQVUCC

```
#ifndef AFOBJECTFACTORY_H
#define AFOBJECTFACTORY_H

struct GameObjectComponent_t
{   
  struct GameObjectComponent_t* next;
};
typedef struct GameObjectComponent_t GameObjectComponent;

struct Sprite_t
{   
  GameObjectComponent GameObjectProperties;
  GraphicsComponent   GraphicsProperties;
  PhysicsComponent    PhysicsProperties;
};
typedef struct Sprite_t Sprite;

Sprite* CreateSprite(int color, 
                     int screenX, int screenY, int worldX, int worldY, 
                     int h, int w);

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't include the other headers, which supposedly contain the definitions of `GraphicsComponent` and `PhysicsComponent`. You should add something like

```
#include "otherHeader.h"
```

before the struct definitions above.

#### Update

There is a cyclic dependency between your headers: both AFGraphics.h and AFPhysics.h `#include` AFObjectFactory.h. You must eliminate this cyclic dependency in order for the code to compile.

The most straightforward way is to replacee the #includes in AFObjectFactory.h with forward declarations of your other structs:

```
struct GraphicsComponent_t;
struct PhysicsComponent_t;

struct GameObjectComponent_t
{   
  struct GameObjectComponent_t* next;
};
typedef struct GameObjectComponent_t GameObjectComponent;

struct Sprite_t
{   
  GameObjectComponent GameObjectProperties;
  struct GraphicsComponent_t GraphicsProperties;
  struct PhysicsComponent_t PhysicsProperties;
};
```

But the better long term approach would be to move stuff around between the headers to sort out the proper order in which they need to be defined, and the headers `#include`d.

E.g. right now AFPhysics.h contains the definition of `PhysicsComponent`, and some methods with `Sprite` parameters. This makes it impossible for the compiler to parse the headers without a forward declaration, as AFObjectFactory.h and AFPhysics.h mutually depend on each other.

If you moved the method declarations with `Sprite` parameters into AFObjectFactory.h, the dependency of AFPhysics.h on AFObjectFactory.h ceased to exist, thus you could remove the `#include "AFObjectFactory.h"` line from AFPhysics.h and instead `#include AFPhysics.h` in AFObjectFactory.h, eliminating the need to forward declare `struct PhysicsComponent_t` there. (Of course, other arrangements are possible too - this is just the simplest which comes to my mind. The point is to group your definitions in headers so that there is always a well defined include order, without cyclic dependencies.)

Comment: Those includes are contained in AFObjectFactory.c file, do they also need to be included within the AFObjectFactory.h file?

Comment: @Aux: other c files won't see the content of AFObjectFactory.c, so yes.

Comment: I've tried including those headers in AFObjectFactory.h and I'm still encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Aux, please post the relevant parts from those other headers, and your updated AFObjectFactory.h .

Comment: @Péter Török Sure thing, I will upload them to pastebin.

Comment: @Péter Török Wow!  Thank you for the excellent response, I will take a second look at my code.

Comment: I see your point Peter, I am in a difficult situation due to my files being cross-dependent of each other.  I am trying to emulate a compositional based design for my game by having the Graphics/Physics components as separate structures with Sprites/Triggers/Decals being composed of the necessary structure components.  i.e.: If a game object needed physics properties it would have a PhysicsComponent member struct that contains all of the physics member variables.

Is there a valid way to implement this in C?

Comment: @Aux, sure, you just need to separate lower and higher level stuff into different headers. Since `Sprite` is a higher level entity, all functions with `Sprite` parameters are higher level too, so you must not declare them in lower level headers. Etc. If you don't want to put these functions into AFObjectFactory.h, create a separate header for them which #includes AFObjectFactory.h.